# What is the answer of below SQL statements

Tags: sql, database

Recently I was going through some online job interview questions and found below multiple choice question on SQL.

Tables `EMPLOYEES` has 5 rows. Consider the following sequence of SQL statements.

```
SQL>CREATE TABLE myTable SELECT AS (SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES);
SQL>INSERT INTO myTable SELECT * FROM myTable;
SQL>INSERT INTO myTable SELECT * FROM myTable;
SQL>INSERT INTO myTable SELECT * FROM myTable;
SQL>INSERT INTO myTable SELECT * FROM myTable
```

If the SQL statement SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable; is executed after executing all the statements listed above, what will be printed is

```
a) 80 
b) 25 
c) 20 
d) 5
```

I thought the answer is 25, but that online portal is saying the correct answer is 80.

But how, not sure! Can anybody help?

Comment: The data you provided is not complete..This type of questions,will be well received when you provide DDL,DML and also your attempt

Comment: Please take some time to look at this link to know more on how to improve question(https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: @TheGameiswar, Actually this is the exact question.

Comment: sorry i missed this part `Tables EMPLOYEES has 5 rows`

Comment: Sad you couldn't just quickly set this up to try and figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

80 is the correct answer.

After

```
 CREATE TABLE myTable AS (SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES);
```

there are 5 rows in MYTABLE.

After `INSERT INTO myTable SELECT * FROM myTable` there are 10 rows in MYTABLE.

After `INSERT INTO myTable SELECT * FROM myTable` there are 20 rows in MYTABLE.

After `INSERT INTO myTable SELECT * FROM myTable` there are 40 rows in MYTABLE.

After `INSERT INTO myTable SELECT * FROM myTable` there are 80 rows in MYTABLE.

At this point `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MYTABLE` will return `80`.

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/846d92e/2)

Answer (score 4):

Edited Answer : The answer will be 80 because

1. Step : myTable : 5  (INSERT INTO myTable SELECT * FROM myEmployees;)
2. Step : myTable : 5 + myTable => 10
3. Step : myTable : 10 + myTable => 20
4. Step : myTable : 20 + myTable => 40
5. Step : myTable : 40 + myTable => 80
   You can see the details here http://rextester.com/TQHFE11034